# Stuck on looping through a form.select in Rails (using Elastic Search/Searchkick aggs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm totally stuck on looping through a form.select in Rails (using Elastic Search/Searchkick aggs).

I can access the 'bucket' array (and thus "key" and "doc_count") when I don't pre-pend the form.select helper, but it just doesn't loop through when it's there. Not sure how I would get the options dynamically otherwise!

Does anyone know what might be going wrong (ignore the link_to stuff, I'll be changing that once I can get the actual "key")? Perhaps I'm using the form.select helper incorrectly? Thanks!

```
<% form.select @jobs.aggs["location"]["buckets"].each do |bucket| %>
     <% if params[:location] == bucket["key"].to_s %>
        <strong><%= link_to bucket["key"], request.params.except(:location)%></strong>
      <% else %>
         <%= link_to bucket["key"], request.params.merge(location: bucket["key"])%>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try printing `puts @jobs.aggs["location"]["buckets"]` in your controller make sure that you are accessing the array correctly.

Comment: @ricks Thank you for your reply! I've tried this by raising after the each, and putting it in my controller and checking the localhost logs, and it is printing this correctly. It's unfortunately still saying |bucket| (or anything else in the each loop, whether that be "key", "doc_count" etc.) is nil.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! It was a syntax error on my part, as I forgot to use :location in the first part of the form.select, and additionally didn't wrap the block after this in [] brackets (presumably the options have to be in an array or hash with this helper).

Here is the code (simplified) which solved this for me:

```
<% form.select :location, [@jobs.aggs["location"]["buckets"].each do |bucket| %>
  <%= bucket["key"] %>
<% end ] %>
```